# Segmentation fault when reading 5GB XML file

Tags: linux, memory, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run some software that reads a 5GB XML file. When I run it and pass it the file, I get the following error:

```
reading ../../path/to/file.xml ... Segmentation fault
```

So I ran it again under debugger and printed the backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xffffffffff600000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xffffffffff600000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000053324d in gettimeofday ()
#2  0x000000000043bda9 in XML_Parse ()
#3  0x000000000041c2c7 in mzpSAXHandler::parseOffset(long) ()
#4  0x000000000042519a in mzpSAXMzxmlHandler::load(char const*) ()
#5  0x0000000000419561 in rampOpenFile(char const*) ()
#6  0x000000000040c8e3 in MSToolkit::MSReader::readMZPFile(char const*, MSToolkit::Spectrum&, int) ()
#7  0x00000000004075ae in MangoSearchManager::READ_MZXMLSCANS(char*) ()
#8  0x0000000000407a1c in MangoSearchManager::DoAnalysis() [clone .part.164] ()
#9  0x0000000000402792 in main ()
(gdb)
```

But I'm unsure how to interpret the backtrace. Is the most recent command issued the "#0" ? Why is the function/method annotated as '??'

Is it likely this issue could be fixed by running the software on a machine with more RAM? Here is the output of `ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 101722
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 101722
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Please let me know what additional information I can provide to help troubleshoot this issue. Apologies as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

The crash stack trace is suggestive of a stack overflow.

It's possible that `XML_Parse()` (or its callers) is trying to read the entire  file into a stack-allocated buffer.

You can confirm or disprove this by using the following GDB commands at crash point:

```
(gdb) fr 0
(gdb) p/x $rsp
                 # should print $1 = 0x7f...
(gdb) up 100
(gdb) p/x $rsp
                 # should print $2 = 0x7f...
(gdb) p $2 - $1
```

Your stack limit is 8MiB. If the delta between `$2` and `$1` is close to or exceeds 8388608, that would confirm stack overflow as the root cause.

You *may* be able to work around this by using `ulimit -s unlimited`, but your best bet is to contact the author of this program -- reading entire file(s) into a stack buffer is never a smart thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out ASAP!